# What is HTTP/0.9 request?

Tags: http

In the Readme of this project, it is proposed to make some kind of http/0.9 request, what does this mean?

https://github.com/aiortc/aioquic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP/0.9 is a one-line protocol. Its main points are:

- Initial version of HTTP - a simple client-server, request-response, telenet-friendly protocol
- Request nature: single-line (method + path for requested document)
- Methods supported: GET only
- Response type: hypertext only
- Connection nature: terminated immediately after the response
- No HTTP headers (cannot transfer other content type files), No status/error codes, No URLs, No versioning

For details see the article
[Evolution of HTTP — HTTP/0.9, HTTP/1.0, HTTP/1.1, Keep-Alive, Upgrade, and HTTPS](https://medium.com/platform-engineer/evolution-of-http-69cfe6531ba0).

An example of a HTTP/0.9 request:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From this [w3.org source](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) entitled *The Original HTTP as defined in 1991*:

> This document defines the Hypertext Transfer protocol (HTTP) as originally implemented by the World Wide Web initaitive software in the prototype released. This is a subset of the full HTTP protocol, and is known as HTTP 0.9.

Futhermore:

> This restricted protocol is very simple and may always be used when you do not need the capabilities of the full protocol which is backwards compatible.